# How to find a minimal '3D polyhedron' which is similar to A Minimal Circle in the planer graph?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, tessellations

Greetings all and thank you. I'm a Ph.D. candidate working on a 3D tessellation project and get stuck.
I've simplified the system into a set of lines linked together which form **a Line-Framework** (points connectivity list). Now I want to get the tessellation of this Line-Framework in a set of minimal 'convex polyhedra' without changing the connectivity of the points.

Let me give an example for further description.

The **Line-Framework** is described in points pairs, e.g.**{{P1,P2};{P2,P3};{P2,P9}...}**, which can be drawn as follows. (Each $P_i$ has coordinate details for plotting.)

[image: Line-Framework]

And I want to have the enclosed set **{v1={P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8};v2={P9,P2,P3,P6,P7};v3={P10,P11,P1,P4,P5,P8}}**; $V=v1+v2+v3$. For set $v2$: Face1 = $P2-9-6$, $F2$ = $P2-3-9$, $P3-7-9$, $P7-6-9$ and $P2-3-7-6$. This five faces form an enclosed polyhedron. Which I think may similar to find a circle in planer graph.

How can I work out the points set I need?

THANKS!

Comment: Good question, but I would suggest you to try the CS StackExchange also.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: A simple exanple shows that you can't always do that. If you have two adjacent cubes, and you nudge one of the points in the middle a little bit along the edge, the four vertices of the common face of the cubes will no longer be coplanar.

Comment: You're right! I think I need to add more constraints to my simplified model and renew my questions. Thanks!

Comment: If we omit the coordinations and just consider the connectivity of the points,  and this problem may change into a graph. Then, the problem goes to how to find a minimal '3D polyhedron' which is similar to A Minimal Circle in the planer graph. Could this problem be solved? Thanks for your reply!